# What does 'Use OpenGl' do under Unity 2D?

Tags: unity, graphics, opengl, 2d

In Dconf, schema com.canonical.Unity2d has a key named 'use-opengl'. Under description it says 'Whether to render the graphics into an OpenGl viewport'. But does it make any changes on how the desktop looks, or is it just a performance matter?

Answer (score 3):

For cards that support accelerated opengl such as NVidia, this setting will significantly improve performance when switching between viewports and other effects.

Some older cards do not support OpenGl - and as such this setting should be off.  With the setting off, the *Raster* engine is used - this is a software implementation of the viewport effects you see.

It didn't work in Oneiric - but a [fix was released](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/887957) for 12.04.